# Video animation exports as still frames

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, video, cloth-simulation

I tried a flag animation. The .blend file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4q6yuidn3qy77u/ssf.blend?dl=0

The animation preview worked fine. I finalised render settings and exported as ffmpeg mp4 video. It tooks 5hour to me to render out . Finally I got a 30 sec still image video. there is no animation . What wrong have i done?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully rendered out your scene (with different textures since they were not stored in your blend file)

The only advice I can really give you to help you work out what has gone wrong is to: export a few frames and test to see if they move first before rendering out the entire clip.

Only exporting a few frames at a time will allow you to adjust and fix up your render settings and find out what is wrong

[image]